# Doxygen how to separate classes by path?

Tags: c++, class, doxygen

So how exactly does one separate classes by path in Doxygen? I have tried with groups and sections,but for some reason, it would always combine classes with same name.

Current file structure is as following:

```
Trunk
 |
 +-> Client -> DemoClass.h
 |
 +-> Server -> DemoClass.h
 |
 +-> Shared -> OtherClass.h
```

Problem is I don't want a 1x DemoClass in doxygen that contains all the functions combined i want 2 seperate sections/class as in Server/DemoClass, Client/DemoClass.

Comment: I'd rename them to `clientDemo.h` and `serverDemo.h`.

Comment: Can't rename them, we are talking doxygen to help documenting not screwing up 10000 lines of code.

Comment: If your demos are really 10000 lines of code, you need some serious rewriting anyway.

Comment: Groups, so long as you use them correctly and make sure the two are added to different groups, which are then closed, should solve this.

Comment: Really, I need rewriting cause they are different projects? Maybe learn to program before you speak? I am asking for a solution without code changes, cause I refuse to believe anyone would write a software that is incapable of handling multiple projects.

Comment: Thanks Peachykeen, but in Client main.h I added // \defgroup Client and in Server main.h I added // \defgroup Server. I tried both \ingroup and \addgroup in the start of DemoClass.h.
Which worked fine in the sense that it makes a new Module tab, but when I click on Classes, they are still combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation, see bullet 4 of http://www.doxygen.org/manual/trouble.html.

I recommend to make separate projects, one for the server and one for the client, as they can never be legally in one executable anyway, or use namespaces.

File names can be the same, that's not a problem.

Comment: Yeah, well the point of it was to draw UML diagrams that connected them, and cut off some time in doing that, cheers for the answer. The documentation confused me, since it writes "it should ignore all of the classes with the same name except one.", but it combined them, so I was hoping we where talking about some kinda option/flag for disabling the combination.